# table break html php, invoice report for php

Tags: php, html, css, printing, report

Is there such thing as a table break?

I am trying to make an invoice like page in html, example:

```
<header>Something</header>
    <table style="height:500px">
    <tr><th>Count</th><th>Item</th><th>Qty</th></tr>
    <!-- Loop some data in the database-->
<tr><td>Loop Data1</td><td>Loop Data1</td><td>Loop Data1</td></tr>
    </table>
<footer>something</footer>
```

NOTE: see this in a printing view, a4 size paper

What i want to achieve is that every page will have header and footer fixed, and it will only goes to the next page if data looped is greater than table's  fixed height

-- Data is always different for each report so i cannot also guarantee the length or height of the Looped data.

Is there anyway to achieve this in php or javascript/jquery?

Is there any plugins that may help do this?

Comment: datatables.net is a good plugin.

Comment: Sorry i am a newbie at this, this is the first time i heard this plug-in.  i looked for datatables, but which particular plug-in is it? the datatables itself is very large, i really have no idea which one can achieve my goal. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to handle with various numbers of pages is using FPDF library. You can define when page breaks in .pdf so it is useful.
If you collect data from MySQL database just create table using "WHILE". It should look like this:

```html
$current_height=100;
$max_table_height=250;

while ($row="something") {

  //add here some cells in current row

  $current_height+=$height_of_cell;
  
  if ($current_height>=$max_table_height) {
    fpdf->AddPage();
    $current_height=100;
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried to test just the samples on my server, it looks like this %PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�M�1�0����7�r&i/����fqm�JLY�V(��as�Z��pς� ��XKڮL�x�>�r=fLC,WЧ���G�ON���%%I��s���e��ZӾ.{ĵ��e0000 n trailer << /Size 8 /Root 7 0 R /Info 6 0 R >> startxref 757 %%EOF no idea why

Comment: You must copy the whole library on your server to make it work and remember about one disadvantage of this library. You can NOT have any "echo" or space before "<?php".